# How to calculate two input form fields and put the value in another without submitting the form using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I know this is an extremely basic question  but I'm stuck on this. 
I have two input boxes and I want to calculate those inputs and show the result  into another input (3rd one) immediately without the need of a submit button.
I means, once I start entering the values into the input and the result will shows live in the 3rd input which is the represent the result...

```
<input type="text" class="input value1">
<input type="text" class="input value2">
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" id="result">

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
      var val1 = $(".value1").val();
      var val2 = $(".value2").val();
      $(".input").keyup(function(){
         $("#result").text(val1+val2);
       });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Put val1 and val2 in keyup statement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".input").keyup(function(){
          var val1 = +$(".value1").val();
          var val2 = +$(".value2").val();
          $("#result").val(val1+val2);
    });
});
```

Look at fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g7zz6/

Comment: Thank you so much, I figured it out :)

Answer (score 1):

just set the text value, also you need to parse them as other wise they will be concatenated as strings.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var val = parseInt($(".value1").val()) + parseInt($(".value2").val());
    $("#result").text(val);
});
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sn2DH/)

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption of SUM as you stated, the inputs will be numberic in nature.

```
$(".input").on("change", function(){
    var ret = Number($(".value1").val()) + Number($(".value2").val());
    $("#result").val(ret);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 function addinput(){ 
   var x= Number(document.getElementById("first").value);
   var y= Number(document.getElementById("second").value);
   var z= Number(x+y);
   document.getElementById("l").value = Number(z);     
 }
```