# Very Basic Math Script Using AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, math

I wanna ask if is it possible to do very basic math inside form's input text field using AJAX? I know its possible with javascript/jquery but I don't want to having to clicking submit button and reload the page to see the result. I want the math calculation with instant result inside the input text field.

example:

Input Text Field 1 + Input Text Field 2 = (Shows Instant Result in Input Text Field 3)

Comment: You can do that using javascript/jQuery. Ajax has nothing to do with it. Use a `change` or `keypress` event

Comment: AJAX would be SLOWER than doing the calculation in browser-side Javascript, and more complex.  The page does not reload in the browser-side javascript method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate two input form fields and put the value in another without submitting the form using jquery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571718/how-to-calculate-two-input-form-fields-and-put-the-value-in-another-without-subm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do the following

http://jsfiddle.net/dharam1987/L9evdhkk/

```
Val 1 <input type="text" name="f1" id="f1" /> <br />
Val 2 <input type="text" name="f2" id="f2" /> <br />
Result <input type="text" name="res" id="res" /> <br />
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="calculate();" />

<script>
    function calculate() {
    var f1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('f1').value);
    var f2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('f2').value);
    var res = f1 + f2;
    document.getElementById('res').value = res;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing it, it was almost what i am looking for except still having to press a button in the jsfiddle. But still, i really thankful for the share

Comment: If you want to do it without pressing the button then you can call that function for both input field elements onkeyup/onkeydown event

ex - `<input type="text" onkeyup="calculate();" name="f2" id="f2" />`

However that is using raw JavaScript if you would like to use JQuery you can do wonders with it and jQuery will also be veryhelpful for you to solve many more complex JS related solutions. Upvote/Accept answer if it has helped you. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! Accepted your answer as I dont have 15 reputation yet to upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using javascript/jQuery. Ajax has nothing to do with it. Use a change or keypress event.

This should give you the idea:

```
$("myInputSelector").on("keyup", function () {

    var theTwoSelectors = $("myInputSelector"),
        total = 0;

    theTwoSelectors.each(function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if(value)
            total += parseInt(value);
    });

    $("myResultSelector").val(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple HTML

Lets try an Example for the above requirement
example:

We can simply use the  tag
here the below output tag will show the result of input tag "a" value multiply by 5...

```
<form oninput="o.value = parseInt(a.value) *5">
    <input type="number" id="a" name="a">
    <output name="o" id="o"></></output>
    </form>
```

more information please refer this link http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_output.asp

Comment: Can you explain what your code does? It would make your answer more helpful.